# Get value from another model in case of ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to get value from foreign key from another model and subscribe it.
It works when field is declared as `ForeignKey` but when field is declared as `ManyToManyField` it not works.
How can I do it?

Please help.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    text = models.ForeignKey(Text, null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Language, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.text = self.project.text                     #WORKS
        self.language  = self.project.language.all()      #NOT WORKS
        super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this works?

```
class Document(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    text = models.ForeignKey(Text, null=True, blank=True)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)  # no need to null/blank + put the name on plural if using a many to many relation.

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.text = self.project.text
        super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # super() must be called BEFORE feeding your many to many.
        project_languages = self.project.languages.all()
        self.languages.add(*project_languages)
```

When using a many to many field attribute, you need to wait for your instance is created before adding values in your many to many attribute.
You do this with `add`, contrary to foreign key fields.

Comment: It not works :(
`print (self.language.all())` after all return correct array of languages, but in admin form options are not selected and not saved in database

Comment: `print (self.language.all())` after all return correct array of languages, but  options are not selected in admin form and not saved in database

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**`.add()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for initializing ManyToManyField

Change this line

```
# use plural naming convention when its ManyToMany relation `language` should be `languages` in your Document model
self.language  = self.project.language.all()
```

to

```
# call save method of super class before adding values to many-to-many 
super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
p_language = self.project.language.all()
self.language.add(*p_language)
```

So you must call `save` before adding the many-to-many relationship. Since add immediately affects the database, you do not need to save afterwards.